# Is a single page website satisfies ICANN's UDRP 4 - Legitimate Interests in a domain?

Tags: domains, domain-registration, domain-registrar, icann

ICANN's [UDRP](https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/policy-2012-02-25-en) 4 states that

> You are required to submit to a mandatory
>   administrative proceeding in the event that a third party (a
>   "complainant") asserts to the applicable Provider, in compliance with
>   the Rules of Procedure, that
>
> 1. your domain name is identical or confusingly similar to a
>      trademark or service mark in which the complainant has rights; and
> 2. you have no rights or legitimate interests in respect of the domain name; and
> 3. your domain name has been registered and is being used in bad faith.

If a domain is registered, and immediately afterwards it is serving a single webpage that offers the domain for sale and in addition it offers additional services like web-design, logo-design, web development, online marketing, eCommerce solutions, and so on - does this satisfies the `legitimate interests` in the domain name clause?

Many of the domain names that are offering for sale are usually parked with the registrar or with a parking provider and it displays ads in addition to a note that the domain is for sale. In this case, I would think that the fact that the domain is parked and generates revenue from ads should satisfy the `legitimate interests` clause, am I right?

Comment: It also depends on which country you are in.  In New Zealand, for example, there is an anti-squatting legislation in force.

Answer (score -1):

For things like that, your best advise is to consult your attorney, or another one specialised in UDRPs and such procedures. Things are not black and white, you will probably find out in past cases that some would have been in your direction, others in the opposite.

The situation also depends on lot if the "legitimate" owner contacts you to get back the domain name and how you reply to him.